# How to add callbacks to Framework Element's Visibility Dependency Property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm using a dependency property which handles the fade-in / fade-out of a Framework Element.

The property is able to handle the fade-in / fade-out animation by registering callback methods for whenever the Visibility property of the animated element has changed.

This was done by the previous coder as such:

```
UIElement.VisibilityProperty.AddOwner(typeof (FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, VisibilityChanged,                                                                           CoerceVisibility));
```

The problem here is that FrameworkElement is already an owner of the VisibilityProperty, and as such triggers an exception which was catched (luckily) by ExpressionBlend.

To counter this problem, I noticed that Dependency Properties have a "OverwriteMetadata" method, which allows someone to overwrite the metadata of a given type, in my case FrameworkElement.

As such, I could use the following instead:

```
UIElement.VisibilityProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible, VisibilityChanged, CoerceVisibility));
```

My question is:

How safe is it to overwrite FrameworkElement's Visibility's metadata ? If its unsafe, what other alternatives do I have ?

EDIT: Well, scratch that... Apparently overwriting the metadata triggers another exception: "PropertyMetadata is already registered for type 'FrameworkElement'.

How can I add the callback methods for the dependency property, if I'm unable to add an owner or overwrite the metadata ?

Am I forced to create a class which derives from FrameworkElement, add it as an owner of the VisibilityProperty, and make all controls who use that property be of the same type as the derived class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there exist no other hooks, you can use [`DependencyPropertyDescriptor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dependencypropertydescriptor.aspx) to add changed handlers:

```
var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(FrameworkElement.VisibilityProperty, typeof(FrameworkElement));
desc.AddValueChanged(this.OnVisibilityChanged);
```

However, `FrameworkElement` defines an `IsVisibleChanged` event - could you use that?

Comment: Excellent ! I noticed that it doesn't provide support for additional Coerce callbacks, which is the callback I'm mostly interested in overwriting (its null by default for FrameworkElement). Any way to modify the "Coerce Value" callback ? EDIT: I stand corrected, I believe I could use "DesignerCoerceValueCallback".

Comment: "However, FrameworkElement defines an IsVisibleChanged event - could you use that?" - I was mostly interested in overwriting the Coerce Value callback, which defaults to null for FrameworkElements. I simply used the "DesignerCoerceValueCallback" property of "DependencyPropertyDescription" to add my callback. It seems to work, though I'm not sure how valid that solution is :)