# WPF DockPanel.SetDock event

Tags: wpf, events, dockpanel

I need to capture the DockPanel.SetDock for a given FrameworkElement,
like this example:

```
        var textBlock = new TextBlock();
        textBlock.DockChanged += (s, e) => { DoWork(); };
```

DoWork() should be invoked when I call:

```
        DockPanel.SetDock(textBlock, Dock.Right);
```

Someone know how to do this or something to get the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
m_TextBlock is your own control which need moniter the DockChanged

```
var desc = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(DockPanel.DockProperty, typeof(DockPanel));
desc.AddValueChanged(m_TextBlock,this.OnDockChanged);
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7727687/5189077)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it works very well. Sorry for late